# Implement time range slicer for ZingCharts scatter plot

Tags: zingchart

I am trying to implement a time range slicer for a ZingCharts scatter plot in my application.

The requirement is similar to [this chart done using DC.JS and CrossFilter.JS](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/):

#### Chart with time range slicer

[image: Chart with time range slicer]

Would appreciate if you could guide me on some examples, best practises and ideas to implement it. Thanks